# WooCommerce - Replace Shipping Label in email template

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Maybe this is a duplicate but I really have problems to find it anywhere on Google, Stackoverflow etc.

I always have issues in WooCommerce changing the email templates, it very anoying and not user friendly. But my question, where or how can I change the "Shipping" label in the email templates that customers and admins receive?

Do I need to add some hook or can I replace it in the php files?

I already searched the php files and not able to find it...

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of emails that are sent out within Woo-commerce, and there's also a number of templates which pull in specific order data into the email itself. To find these templates, you can go to :

woocommerce/templates/emails/ (this is within the plugin folder)

What you want to do at this point is basically make a copy of the email templates you wish to edit, and save them within the following location: your_theme/woocommerce/emails/ . What this will do is essentially create a child template of the main one that Woo-commerce uses, such that in the case that the plugin updates, you will not lose any changes done to the respective email template.

If you wish to...for example edit the email that the administrator gets when a new order is placed, this template is located here (within your plugin folder) woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php

Here's the actual code from the respective template so you know you've found the right one I've mentioned:

```
<?php
/**
 * Admin new order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails/HTML
 * @version 2.5.0
 */

 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
 }

 /**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

 <p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ); ?></p>

 <?php

 /**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
  * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
  * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
  * @since 2.5.0
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

 /**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

 /**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
  * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

 /**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Remember, there's still a number of hooks within these templates themselves that you may have to hook onto depending on what you're trying to actually change within the template, however for the most part since you now know where to find them, this should be relatively straight forward.

Hope this helps! Good luck :)